# ¿Con cuales fuentes puedo usar la propiedad font-stretch?

Tags: css, css3, fuentes, google-fonts

Se que puedo usar font-stretch para expandir fuentes, pero solo unas pocas fuentes obedecen a esta propiedad. ¿Cómo puedo saber si una fuente de google fonts o cualquier otro sitio tiene esta opcion?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que, por favor, traduzcas tu pregunta a español -incluido el título-. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 1):

las fuentes que permiten el uso de font-stretch son las denominadas `Variable Fonts`. Las más conocidas son TrueType y OpenType.
Te dejo un link donde puedes encontrar más: [Variable-Fonts](https://v-fonts.com/)

Espero que te sirva.